# Highchart + Plotly dash Graph displaying before pressing the button

Tags: javascript, highcharts, plotly-dash

I have embedded plotly dash with highchart . My requirement is when I press the Apply button the graph should be displayed . But when I run the code itself the graph is displaying .

```
import dash
import dash_alternative_viz as dav
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import random

external_scripts = [
    "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js",
    "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js",
    "http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js",
    "http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js",
    "http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/maps/world.js",
    "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/draggable-points.js"

]
app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_scripts=external_scripts)

app.layout = html.Div([
  html.Button(id="my_button", children="Apply!"),
  dav.HighChart(id="my_highchart")
])

@app.callback(
  Output("my_highchart", "options"), [Input("my_button", "n_clicks")])
  
def random_chart(n_clicks):

  return {
      'title': { 'text': 'Highcharts draggable demo' },
      'series': [{
        'data': [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,30.9, 41.5, 189, 162.2, 90.0, 45.0, 105.6, 136.5, 389.4, 500.1, 25.6, 69.4],
        'color':'white',
        'marker': {
                'fillColor': 'blue',
                  },
        'cursor': 'move',
          'dragDrop': {
            'draggableX': False,
            'draggableY': True
               }
    }]
  }
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server( port = 8052, debug=True)
```

Im not sure what could be the issue , can someone help me ?

Thanks,
Meera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default, all callbacks are executed on initialization in Dash. You can bypass this behavior for all callbacks via the `prevent_initial_callbacks` keyword argument of the `Dash` object,

```
app = Dash(..., prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
```

or on a per callback basis via the `prevent_initial_call` keyword argument of the callback decorator,

```
@app.callback(Output(...), Input(...)], prevent_initial_call=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @emher , its working as expected now.